# php database not being updated when form submited

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a PHP code to update the database through a form, however, the data never seems to make it through to the database! My code below (just to let you know that the PHP code above the start of the HTML code is in a separate doc called post.inc.php):

```html
<?php
    include_once 'Includes/dbh.inc.php';
    
    $Title = $_POST['Title'];
    $content = $_POST['Text1'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (title, main) VALUES ('$Title', '$content');";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    header("Location: ../Backend.php?Post=success");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Backend</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" tyle="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="head">
        <h1>Make A Post</h1>
        <a href="Backend.delete.php">delete a post</a>
    </div>                    
<form action="Includes/Post.inc.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id = "title" name="Title" placeholder="Title">
    <br>
    <textarea name="Text1" id= "content" placeholder="Content(1000 charecter limit)...." cols="90" rows="20"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" id = "submit" name="submit">Post!</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code will always forward to `Backend.php` no matter you submit your form or not. It's an obvious logical error, and there are quite a lot mistakes in HTML.

Comment: could you head me in the write direction, im new to php? thanks

Comment: Does your form even display on the page? It seems that you are setting a header before the html loads

Comment: the form does display as i said in the question the top php code is in a seperate document

Answer (score 2):

To fix the issue, you should rewrite the PHP part as follow:

```
<?php
    require_once('Includes/dbh.inc.php');

    if(isset($_POST['Title'], $_POST['Text1'])) {
            $Title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Title']);
            $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Text1']);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (title, main) VALUES ('$Title', '$content');";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if($result !== false) {
                     header("Location: ../Backend.php?Post=success");
                     exit;
            } else {
                     // query failed, do some checks
            }
    }
?>
```

You have to:

1. escape the input from user to prevent SQL Injection.
2. check whether the form is submitted as POST

Also, as mentioned in comments, the HTML is full of errors. You'd better use W3C HTML Validator to check your HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    include_once 'Includes/dbh.inc.php';

    $Title = $_POST['Title'];
    $content = $_POST['Text1'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (title, main) VALUES ('$Title', '$content');";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    header("Location: ../Backend.php?Post=success");
?>
```

Please remove the bolded semi colon , and your code should be

```
<?php
    include_once 'Includes/dbh.inc.php';

    $Title = $_POST['Title'];
    $content = $_POST['Text1'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (title, main) VALUES ('$Title', '$content')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    header("Location: ../Backend.php?Post=success");
?>
```

or you may use

```
<?php
        include_once 'Includes/dbh.inc.php';
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $Title = $_POST['Title'];
        $content = $_POST['Text1'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (title, main) VALUES ('$Title', '$content')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        header("Location: ../Backend.php?Post=success");
        }else{
            echo "Error";
        }
    ?>
```